# simple calculation of field for php mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, database, calculated-field

i have simple db that it is filled by a form from a page, all is ok in the entry.

i have 2 fields in the database are: all_students and current_students filled by the user in the form that i want to  calculate

the trick is that i am echoing only the latest db record in the output page.. to give me only the latest data inserted in the form...

now, i want to create a new field that give me the absent students automatically (all - current)

what i have tried, i read that i can NOT create a new calculated field in the db, it is not an excel, so i am trying to echo the calculation results of these 2 fields, to a new value that is the "absent students"

what you suggest? please help, here is my code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","PasswordHere","DBnameHere");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, class, all_students, current_students FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "Class: " . $row['class'] . "<br>";
  echo "All students: " . $row['all_studnets'] . "<br>";
  echo "Current students: " . $row['current_studnets'] . "<br>";

  echo "Absent students: " . $row['all_studnets'] . - . $row['current_studnets'] . "    <br>";

  }


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: remove the periods by the minus sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only put dot (.) if you want to concatenate a string. Please remove the dot since you are subtracting.

```
 echo "Absent students: ";
 echo floatval($row['all_studnets'])  -  floatval($row['current_studnets']);
 echo "<br>";
```

Comment: that did not work, note that those 2 fields are varchar in db and it gives negative value without label! gives like -40 only! strange.. but also i am suspecting that $row is not selected in the query, as it is calculated one, and i am echoing only the only last record from the db as shown in the query, does that matter? what is wrong?

Comment: @MikeDerik, if you echo $row['all_studnets'] and $row['current_studnets'].. what are you getting? are you getting the right info from the db?

Comment: yes, individual fields are working fine, fetching ok.

Comment: also, if i   echo "Absent students: " . $row['all_students' - 'current_students']. "<br>"; gives me the id number of the record!!!  and i    echo "Absent students: " . $row['all studnets'] - $row['current_students']. "<br>"; it gives negative value the same as (current_student) value but negative like -40

Comment: perfect, that works :) thanks a lot dear, really appreciated :), i couldn't vote up to your answer, although it worked perfect

Comment: Ill be glad to help. Just accept the answer if you cant vote up. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this line

```
echo "Absent students: " . $row['all_studnets']  -  $row['current_studnets'] . "    <br>";
```

Insted of this

```
echo "Absent students: " . $row['all_studnets'] . - . $row['current_studnets'] . "    <br>";
```